# Win8.1 search is not sufficient to me. What can I use?

Tags: windows-8

I am using an updated windows 8.1 machine.

I want to search my computer and not the whole internet, I want to search specific drives and not the whole computer, I want to search folders and not whole drives........... This 8.1 search is just not configurable for me.

I loved the Win95, 98, 2k, etc. I hate 8.1 search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a smarter Find files utility for Windows 8 than Windows key + F?](http://superuser.com/questions/511068/is-there-a-smarter-find-files-utility-for-windows-8-than-windows-key-f)

Comment: ( I am confused ) it works exactly like it always did.  You open the drive then search for files.

Comment: I have used the search charm, which is not the same as it always was.     I have also used the search window in windows explorer as well and it does not work the same way.

Comment: The search function in explorer should work in the same way as previous versions of WIndows, but better with more functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two I know (and use sometimes):

- [Everything Search Engine](http://www.voidtools.com/)
- [SearchMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_my_files.html)

Hope it could help.